# Prevent automatic loading of next video on YouTube (esp playlists)

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I absolutely hate it when I watch a video on YouTube and it automatically loads another video page after it's done playing.  This is especially annoying when I'm in the middle of typing a comment as it will cause me to lose what I have typed.

I'd like the video to simply stop and for no further action to take place once it is finished playing.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to remove the portion of the URL from the `&list=` part to the end, however, that takes you out of the playlist mode so you can't see the videos in sequence in the playlist box.

The only reliable way I've found to prevent playlist autoplay *without* leaving the playlist mode is to use the [No Playlist Autoplay For YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-playlist-autoplay-for/dkokllldoffaconpbmbaofjbadhjggil?hl=en) Chrome extension. It only works in Chrome and it's annoying that you have to use an extension for this but it works.

Comment: There's also a firefox extension that works. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/no-playlist-autoplay-for-yt/?src=search

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  There are two icons/buttons above the playlist videos to the right of the currently playing video.  They look like they are for "Repeat" and "Shuffle" but the one that looks like "Repeat" is actually "Autoplay" and disabling that seems to do the trick... for now.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks...  (edit:  it says I have to wait 2 days)

Comment: @vertigoelectric: That's 2 days, not 2 years!

Comment: Doesn't work! But this does: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108618/how-can-i-disable-playlist-autoplay-in-youtube

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: The one that looks like "Repeat" says "Loop" for me. So that's no good.