# Prevent YouTube autoplay

Tags: youtube

I use Chrome. After I watch any video at YouTube it connects to another one without even asking. How can I delete that, so that one video finishes, that's all?

Comment: Mind that in a playlist, you cannot turn off the auto-play, see [How to disable auto-play in YouTube playlists](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117601/how-to-disable-auto-play-in-youtube-playlists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube started an autoplay experiment last year.

Here's [YouTube's guide](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6172631?hl=en) on how to turn off autoplay.

> You can turn off autoplay in your browser so that it is disabled for all videos, as long as they are not in a playlist. Here’s how to turn
> off autoplay:
>
> 1. Click the gear icon in the corner of the video player
> 2. Select OFF next to the Autoplay option
>
> Alternatively, you can use the  toggle above
> the Up Next section on the video page to turn off autoplay.
>
> Note that autoplay will remain turned off until you turn it back on
> again.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, and there are many others, sorted by age, beginning with the oldest:

- [Prevent automatic loading of next video on YouTube (esp playlists)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/142641/253420) (easy and best workaround! But the next answer is the same and older)
- [How can I disable playlist autoplay in YouTube? [duplicate]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/108620/253420) (easy and best workaround!)
- [How to disable auto-play in YouTube playlists](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117601/how-to-disable-auto-play-in-youtube-playlists) (real answer, this is not just a workaround; but needs a script which will change your overall settings; too much of it I guess)

Still, there might be one other workaround which should be the easiest overall. If you are in a playlist, which looks like this:

[image]

You cannot see the "switch autoplay on/off" button. Then, copy just the title of the video, search for it on Youtube, and run it from there. Do not click on anything that is called mix/playlist.

By this, you will have left the playlist. And the "switch autoplay" button will be there again:

[image]