# How to disable auto-play in YouTube playlists

Tags: youtube, user-interface, autoplay

*So I know this question has been asked before, but neither the answers on this question: ([How can I disable playlist autoplay in YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108618/how-can-i-disable-playlist-autoplay-in-youtube/108620#108620)), nor the answers from the linked duplicate question there, work for the behavior I want.*

I want to disable the autoplay feature in a YouTube playlist, and I specifically want to *stay* in the playlist.

For example, I have a playlist of educational videos, I want to watch them all in order and can't rely on the normal next-video suggestion with autoplay. But when the video is over, I want to stop for a little bit, scroll down, read comments etc. Instead Youtube immediately loads the next video, without even the normal 5 second, cancelable delay like in normal autoplay. Basically I want the normal autoplay, which stops for 5 seconds, can be stopped with a cancel button, and gets paused automatically when you scroll down to the comments; but in a playlist.

Another use case might be when a video ends with a minute of advertisement or meaningless blabber, and you forget to pause you suddenly get kicked off the comments when the video ends.

I don't get why YouTube doesn't implement this feature, it seems so useful. Not all playlists are used just for music! So my question:

Do you know of any workaround, plugin, mirror website or anything else which brings me closer to my desired behavior?

Comment: It pisses me off that it's impossible to disable autoplay in playlists.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out a script that works as a workaround. It basically pauses the video when there's only just 1 second left.

1. Download [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/)
2. Install [Youtube disable playlist autoplay](https://greasyfork.org/zh-TW/scripts/375429-youtube-disable-playlist-autoplay) script.
3. Enjoy

(The script has a side effect, though. It will still run even it's not a playlist video, pausing it 1 second before the end.)

Comment: Without having tried it, I wonder whether I can turn it on afterwards again?

Comment: I don't use this script anymore so I don't know how well this works now.

Answer (score 1):

Johan's solution works fine for me. You can also prevent the mentioned side effects by editing the 7th line in the script to

```
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*&list=*
```

With this it will only run with playlists.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bookmarklet (a bookmark with a "URL" field that contains a script instead of specifying a webpage) with the following contents:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('canplay', () => document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].pause())})();
```