# How to get the direct link to a video loaded from a playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I use YouTube playlists to categorize videos I save.

For example I have a "Science" playlist for science videos.

When launch a video from a playlist I am no longer interested in the playlist.

I do  want to watch subsequent videos from the playlist and would like the Web app to behave the same way it would if I had opened a direct link to the video as opposed to opening it from the playlist.

Is there a button or menu option that would allow me to access the video directly regardless if opened from a playlist?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. It might be possible that you are overcomplicating this... have you considered getting the link to the video from the share button? Anyway, you might have to get familiar with the YouTube terms by looking around the YouTube user interface and at the Help Center. Please show what you have tried, include links to the most relevant questions from this site and the relevant YouTube help articles and explain why they don't meet your needs.

Comment: ...  and make your question specific about where you get stuck.

Comment: @BlindSpots I'm looking for most convenient UX path that gets me from `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123&list=...` to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123`. So far I know two ways. 1) edit page address 2) use share feature. Some kind of "autoplay off" feature might work as well in some cases but sounds unnecessarily complicated. I truly wish the playlist to go away. I have no need for the playlist after I have found the video I wanted.

Comment: @cyberixae I I'm suggesting the autoplay off feature because it is the ***least*** complicated approach if it addresses the core of your need.  Trying to rewrite a URL automatically is more complex.  For example, [autoplay can be shut off](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6327615?hl=en#:~:text=Turn%20Autoplay%20on%20or%20off) from the watch screen of any video: At the bottom of the video player, click the Autoplay switch to set it to Off  The setting will stay for that browser until you change it.

Comment: I want to get rid of the playlist and everything that indicates that there ever was a playlist. The [autoplay off question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117601/how-to-disable-auto-play-in-youtube-playlists) communicates a desire to stay in the playlist, and only prevent proceeding to the next video automatically. I have no such desire. I wish the playlist to go away. Since the auto-play off solution involves a browser extension, it is already relatively complicated. If I were to install a browser extension, I would at least want it to fully detach the video from the playlist.

Comment: You don't need a browser extension, to disable auto-play.  YouTube supports this natively. You need a browser extension if you want to start rewriting URLs and the question is no longer a YouTube question but rather a browser question which would be answered on [su]. There are options available to do that. Let me know and I'll make it a good fit for them and migrate it over.

Comment: I assume it is Chrome browser you are  using?

Comment: I thought answers involving the user interacting with the URL somehow would be allowed since it is web apps we are talking here. I guess there are not that many solutions to the problem in case the URLs are considered opaque. Perhaps using the share button is currently the only way. I still don't understand why this is marked as a duplicate. I was hoping I could use this thread to discover new solutions to the problem as they become available. I can't use the auto-play thread for that, since it explicitly states that the playlist should remain present, which is the opposite of what I wanted.