# How can I disable playlist autoplay in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

When I open on YouTube a video, which is in a playlist, after the video has reached the end another video from that playlist is loaded automatically. In YouTube settings "**Repeat playlist**" button is turned off, "**Autoplay**" is turned off. In addition, the Firefox preference "**Warn me when websites try to redirect or reload the page**" is turned on.

Yet somehow YouTube redirects and loads another web page with another video.

**Is it possible to stop this behavior either through YouTube settings, or through the Firefox preferences?**

Comment: @ale not 100% duplicate, mainly because the answer there does not work when we have the url part "&list", therefore the answer here (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/108620/48230) is the only one that really works, and requires a reload

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate.  The linked question can be solved with a button whereas this answer needs you to change the address bar (which is still a pseudo-solution).  Can't be a duplicate if the answers are different!  Maybe you should read the question more carefully before declaring dup.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the part of the URL that looks like this **&list=RDEMh1nfQXGRbitrlSs8fEQK1g**

Comment: now we just need a plugin to automatically do that I guess, thx! :)

Comment: This stops the repeating, but it also gets you outside of playlist mode to "normal" mode, Youtube should fix this problem asap

Comment: This stops the repeating, but it also gets you outside of playlist mode to "normal" mode, Youtube should fix this problem asap

Comment: @Santropedro This answer is the best workaround out there. After playing, you can then just click on the "Back button" in the browser to get back to the playlist. It should be the overall answer. Sadly, it is hidden in a duplicate. I found it only after checking all dupes. Instead, it should be put in [Prevent YouTube autoplay](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75150/prevent-youtube-autoplay?noredirect=1&lq=1) since that is the website where you go to at first if you do not know that it is just the playlist that drops the "switch autoplay" button.